# how to use number of static cells in UITableView using XIB's

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I have been trying to use static cells using XIB's ,But in cell for row at index path I am getting an error like "Cannot convert return expression of type 'UITableViewCell.Type' to return type 'UITableViewCell'" at the line of "  return UITableViewCell".Can any one help me to do this ,Thanks in advance.

```
extension TriipDetailsViewController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
         let cell  :  TripDriverDetailsCell = tripDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TripDriverDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! TripDriverDetailsCell
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
             let cell  :  TripFareDetailsCell = tripDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TripFareDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! TripFareDetailsCell
             return cell
        }else if indexPath.row == 2 {
             let cell  :  TripPaymentModeCell = tripDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TripPaymentModeCell", for: indexPath) as! TripPaymentModeCell
             return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            return 230

        }else if indexPath.row == 1{
            return 200

        }else if indexPath.row == 2{
            return 120
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let cell : UITableViewCell
   if indexPath.row == 0
{
    cell = tripDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TripDriverDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! TripDriverDetailsCell
}else if indexPath.row == 1 {
    cell = tripDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TripFareDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! TripFareDetailsCell
}else if indexPath.row == 2 {
    cell = tripDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TripPaymentModeCell", for: indexPath) as! TripPaymentModeCell
}else {
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
}
return cell
```

}

Comment: You are returning UITableViewCell however you need to return instance of tableview cell. following code may help
You can check returned type of cell using keyword "is".

Answer (score 2):

Eliminate the `return UITableViewCell`.

Some people might say `return UITableViewCell()`, but I’d rather handle this case as the error that it really is, e.g.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TripDriverDetailsCell", for: indexPath)

    case 1:
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TripFareDetailsCell", for: indexPath)

    case 2:
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TripPaymentModeCell", for: indexPath)

    default:
        fatalError("Unexpected row number \(indexPath.row)")
    }
}
```

The `heightForRowAt` should similarly handle the scenario where the `indexPath.row` is not 0, 1, or 2, e.g.:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: return 230
    case 1: return 200
    case 2: return 120
    default: fatalError("Unexpected row number \(indexPath.row)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Here app getting crashed while registering the cells in viewdidload "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @anisha - Sounds like your table outlet might not be hooked up or something like that. It’s impossible to diagnose based upon what you’ve shared thus far. Confirm exactly which variable is nil that you think shouldn’t be and proceed diagnosing why from there. if you still have problems, post a separate question on this separate topic.

Answer (score 0):

You've got

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'UITableViewCell.Type' to return type 'UITableViewCell

because you **return** a `cell` as `return UITableViewCell` that means you return a whole `UITableViewCell` **class** instead of **single** `UITableViewCell()` therefore in the last you've to **return** `cell` as `return UITableViewCell()`

- e.g.

```
extension TriipDetailsViewController: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0
        {
         let cell  :  TripDriverDetailsCell = tripDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TripDriverDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! TripDriverDetailsCell
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
             let cell  :  TripFareDetailsCell = tripDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TripFareDetailsCell", for: indexPath) as! TripFareDetailsCell
             return cell
        }else if indexPath.row == 2 {
             let cell  :  TripPaymentModeCell = tripDetailsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TripPaymentModeCell", for: indexPath) as! TripPaymentModeCell
             return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell() //Here you've to change
    }
```